# The footer is not at bottom rather its just below the header

Tags: html, css, footer, sections

1. It's sticking to the bottom on the home page but not on other pages.
2. I'm using sections on all pages there are a total of 5 sections on the home page and 1 each on other pages.
3. I am a beginner in coding so please help me out with this problem.
4. **click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Ud4cpMGMQN_w0cQpgC1zYsQzIpwVO0G/view?usp=sharing) to see the video with issue**

---

```css
.copyright p{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.copyright{
    padding: 100px;
    color: white;
}
.footlogo{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}
.navfoot{
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;

}
.foot-btn{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-underline-position: 3px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.foot-btn:hover{
    color: #a200ff;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition: 0.2s;
}
footer{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: #171724;
    max-height: 10cm;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.call{
    display: inline;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
            <footer>
                <div class="call">
                    <div class="copyright">
                        <img src="Images/Banner.png" class="footlogo">
                        <p><span>&#169;</span> Copyright 2021 proudly created by Darshan Daiv</p>
                        <div class="navfoot">
                            <a href="Website.html" class="foot-btn">Home</a>
                            <a href="Alphamesh.html" class="foot-btn">Alphamesh</a>
                            <a href="Aboutme.html" class="foot-btn">About Me</a>
                            <a href="Portfolio.html" class="foot-btn">Portfolio</a>
                            <a href="Contact.html" class="foot-btn">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

Comment: Please share some more code. You could add the header and body to the snippet (or at least an example of each one).

Comment: `html{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    cursor: none;
    height: 100%;
}
.body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 8%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `min-height` on the `<html>` tag and position the `<footer>` with `position:absolute`;

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.copyright p{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.copyright{
    padding: 100px;
    color: white;
}
.footlogo{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}
.navfoot{
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;

}
.foot-btn{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-underline-position: 3px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.foot-btn:hover{
    color: #a200ff;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition: 0.2s;
}
footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: #171724;
    max-height: 10cm;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.call{
    display: inline;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<footer>
                <div class="call">
                    <div class="copyright">
                        <img src="Images/Banner.png" class="footlogo">
                        <p><span>&#169;</span> Copyright 2021 proudly created by Darshan Daiv</p>
                        <div class="navfoot">
                            <a href="Website.html" class="foot-btn">Home</a>
                            <a href="Alphamesh.html" class="foot-btn">Alphamesh</a>
                            <a href="Aboutme.html" class="foot-btn">About Me</a>
                            <a href="Portfolio.html" class="foot-btn">Portfolio</a>
                            <a href="Contact.html" class="foot-btn">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

Comment: I tried your way but it only moves above the main section (on the header) see the difference [relative](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWU5n7Rf325sX_yXMyQLvXwbWtvcPk8a/view?usp=sharing) and [absolute](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVb5VlHM5hqM6iT4jI5tDTYZU3giH9Iw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hey, the problem is solved!. IDK why but, the problem was in the position of the above section it was absolute position, I changed it to relative and it's solved now. But why would a section above the footer change its location?!

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to using pixels rather than cm like you did with max-height.

If you first set your body to height:100%; like this:

```
body{
    height:100%;
{
```

,You can then set your footer to (for instance) 20px . Then you can add a min-height of calc(100vh - 10px).

```
.footer{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

This link explains a lot and gives you other options as well:
https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: Hey, the problem is solved!. IDK why but, the problem was in the position of the above section it was absolute position, I changed it to relative and it's solved now. But why would a section above the footer change its location?!

Comment: Relative positioning is close to static. This means that there are issues with setting right and bottom. I don't know exactly what causes it or why it is solved sometimes, but it happens. Do not use fixed positioning. Fixed sets the header to be relative to the window, not the page. I see that you want your header to be in the bottom of the page when you reach it. Not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` on the footer and reduce its width a bit. Just note that this positioning will make the element's parent unable to compute the element (e.g. Its height won't change). Code:

```css
  .copyright p{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  }
  .copyright{
  padding: 100px;
  color: white;
  }
  .footlogo{
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  }
  .navfoot{
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;

  }
  .foot-btn{
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-underline-position: 3px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  }
  .foot-btn:hover{
  color: #a200ff;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  transition: 0.2s;
  }
  footer{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: #171724;
    max-height: 10cm;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .call{
  display: inline;
  justify-content: space-around;
  }
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="call">
      <div class="copyright">
          <!--Removed the image because it was using space-->
          <p><span>&#169;</span> Copyright 2021 proudly created by Darshan Daiv</p>
          <div class="navfoot">
              <a href="Website.html" class="foot-btn">Home</a>
              <a href="Alphamesh.html" class="foot-btn">Alphamesh</a>
              <a href="Aboutme.html" class="foot-btn">About Me</a>
              <a href="Portfolio.html" class="foot-btn">Portfolio</a>
              <a href="Contact.html" class="foot-btn">Contact</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I tried your way but it only moves above the main section (on the header) see the difference [relative](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWU5n7Rf325sX_yXMyQLvXwbWtvcPk8a/view?usp=sharing) and [absolute](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVb5VlHM5hqM6iT4jI5tDTYZU3giH9Iw/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hey, the problem is solved!. IDK why but, the problem was in the position of the above section it was absolute position, I changed it to relative and it's solved now. But why would a section above the footer change its location?!

Answer (score 0):

The `footer` should be positioned as `fixed` not `relative`

Comment: but the footer is then there always on the screen, I want it to be on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

position of the footer should be 'fixed' and try margin-top: auto; too

```css
.copyright p{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.copyright{
    padding: 100px;
    color: white;
}
.footlogo{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}
.navfoot{
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;

}
.foot-btn{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-underline-position: 3px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.foot-btn:hover{
    color: #a200ff;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    transition: 0.2s;
}
footer{
       position: fixed; 
       margin-top:auto;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: #171724;
    max-height: 10cm;
    align-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.call{
    display: inline;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
            <footer>
                <div class="call">
                    <div class="copyright">
                        <img src="Images/Banner.png" class="footlogo">
                        <p><span>&#169;</span> Copyright 2021 proudly created by Darshan Daiv</p>
                        <div class="navfoot">
                            <a href="Website.html" class="foot-btn">Home</a>
                            <a href="Alphamesh.html" class="foot-btn">Alphamesh</a>
                            <a href="Aboutme.html" class="foot-btn">About Me</a>
                            <a href="Portfolio.html" class="foot-btn">Portfolio</a>
                            <a href="Contact.html" class="foot-btn">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

Comment: but the footer stays on the screen always

Comment: it does come down on its place, but I don't want it to stay on the screen always

Comment: Hey, the problem is solved!. IDK why but, the problem was in the position of the above section it was absolute position, I changed it to relative and it's solved now. But why would a section above the footer change its location?!